# every api call twice in react with redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I have make a project in mern stack and I'm using redux in react js. And I have a make some function in action for get data and insert data in database with node js api.
So I'm facing one problem, I'm submit form one time but data insert two time. And every api calling is twice. I don't know what is happened.

My action code or function.

```
/**
 * @insert data
 */
export const createNewPan = (e, navigate) => async (dispatch) => {
    // console.log('pan data', e)
    try {
        dispatch(loader(true));
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("id", e?.id);
        formData.append("aocode", e.aocode);
        formData.append('sig', e.sig)
        if (e.id != "") {
            const updatepan = await api.put('/apiurl/update', formData, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            })
            // console.log('updatepan', updatepan)
            if (updatepan.status == 200) {
                toast.success(updatepan.data.msg[0].msg)
                // return navigate('/pans')
                dispatch(loader(false));
            }
        } else {
            const res = await api.post('/apiurl/create', formData)
            if (res.status == 200) {
                toast.success('Pan Created')
                dispatch(loader(false));
                return navigate('/pans')
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch(loader(false));
        toast.error(error.response.data.msg[0].msg)
        if (error) {
            if (error.response.status == 401) {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                return navigate('/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call function on submit in Form component

```
 const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createNewPan(panData, navigate)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're react 18? If that's the case then they've changed how react used to work!!

[Check Out Here](https://flaviocopes.com/react-useeffect-two-times/)

Comment: Yes it's I'm understand but on onsubmit not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).